# Code executes without errors but the Excel file is generating with blanks

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-excel

```
import pandas as pd

# Read csv file using Pandas
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", engine="python", **header=None**)

# Add column headers
**df.columns** = ["EmpID", "SSN", "Status", "LastName", "FirstName", "Middle", "DOB", "Address1", "Address2", "City", "State", "Zip", "Phone", "Email", "Gender", "GroupStatus", "Salary", "PayPeriods", "DOH", "MedEligibility", "Association", "Company Number", "TermDate", "TermReasonCode", "LOADate", "LOAReasonCode", "SalaryDateChange", "HourlyRate", "EIN", "SupplementalEligDate", "RecordTerminator"]

# Process dataframes for duplicates and missing data
df0 = df[df.duplicated(subset=["EmpID", "SSN", "LastName", "FirstName", "DOB"])]
df1 = df.loc[df["DOB"].isna(), ["EmpID", "SSN", "LastName", "FirstName", "DOB"]]
df2 = df.loc[df["Address1"].isna(), ["EmpID", "SSN", "LastName", "FirstName", "Address1"]]
df3 = df.loc[df["Gender"].isna(), ["EmpID", "SSN", "LastName", "FirstName", "Gender"]]
df4 = df.loc[df["Association"].isna(), ["EmpID", "SSN", "LastName", "FirstName", "Association"]]

# Print dataframe output to separate tabs in one Excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx") as writer:
    df0.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Duplicates", engine='xlsxwriter', index=True)
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="DOB", index=False)`
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Address1", index=False)
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Gender", index=False) 
    df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Association", index=False)
```

I need to read data from multiple `.csv` files that have the same column format.  When I run the above code, the five tabs generate within an Excel document but none of the column data appears.

Comment: is it reading the csv correctly? Do you get any data by printing dataframe after reading and after adding headers? Like `print(data)` and `print(df)`

Comment: You need to add ***writer.save()***

Comment: I just went through and printed each dataframe (d0, d1, d2, etc.)  They are all populating with NaN.  I salted the test file with rows that should produce errors including duplicates, missing DOBs, etc.  So it sounds like the issue is in the code reading the .csv file, not writing it.

Comment: Figured out issue 1:  data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", engine="python") needs to read as data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", engine="python", header=None) since the .csv files do not include a header row.

Comment: Figured out issue 2: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["EmpID", "SSN",... should instead read as: df.columns=["EmpID", "SSN"...